# How to get Xcode custom build script to accept stdin input

Tags: xcode, scripting

I have a custom build script in Xcode that waits for user input under certain circumstances. Xcode by default seems to skip this and continue regardless of the result.

The strange thing is, the process waiting for input doesn't even exit, Xcode just drives onward without waiting either way.

Is there any way to get user input when running a custom build script in Xcode?